# Why do I get a CORS error after a successful Preflight?

Tags: asp.net-core

I've been struggling with this one for hours. The problem:

I send a POST request from my frontend (Angular, probably irrelevant) and my .NET backend responds with a status code 200 for the preflight request but a CORS error for the following POST request.

I've tried everything possible so I'm probably missing something critical here.

CORS setup on the backend:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
   options.AddDefaultPolicy(
      policy =>
      {
         policy.SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true).AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
      });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
   app.UseSwagger();
   app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
   if (!context.Request.Headers.Any(k => k.Key.Contains("Origin")) || context.Request.Method != "OPTIONS")
   {
      return next.Invoke();
   }
   context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
   return context.Response.WriteAsync("handled");
});
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseCors();
app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

- Browser: Brave, but the same happens on chrome.
- .NET version: net6.0

I tried:

- Enabling CORS for all origin, headers and methods.
- Explicitly enabling my specific origin (without the trailing '/').
- Enabling CORS with the EnableCors attribute on that specific controller.
- Using `SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)` instead of `AllowAnyOrigin()`.
- Restarting the server.
- Deleting the `obj` and `bin`, rebuilding and running again.
- Restarting my computer.
- Using 'no protection' for the 'Safe browsing' option on Brave.
- Changing the order in which the middleware are added.
- Using http instead of https for the server by removing `UseHttpsRedirection()`.
- Change the format of the payload that is being sent.

Comment: Could you check the preflight response headers. You seem to return status `200`, but is the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header present with your origin in it? See: [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) - The HTTP Response Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#the_http_response_headers)

Comment: I tried doing "context.Request.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080");" and also using a wildcard but now I get a 404 for the preflight

Comment: You're still missing the protocol there. An [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin) is protocol + host + port. So it should contain `http://localhost:8080` The wildcard should work though.

Comment: Tried again; Preflight is 200, but I still get a CORS error with the POST request.

Comment: I'm getting some very weird behavior, though. The Preflight sometimes returns a 404 even though I haven't changed a thing, and then works again after restarting the server.

Comment: The browser may contains some cache or you don't build the server well. All in all, I suggest you could try to add the origin inside the programs instead of using the default DefaultPolicy.

Comment: I tried adding it, didn't work, also tried clearing the cache and it didn't work.

Comment: Could you post the `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers present in the preflight response (from web-browser pov)? Go to the web-browser developer tools network tab, select the preflight request, and check the response headers.

Comment: I find **stackoverflow** questions to work best when there is an explicit answerable question near the bottom.

Comment: Hey guys. This is most likely not a CORS error but rather something to do with the route mapping. It makes absolutely no sense that a preflight would return a 404.

Comment: Could you please tell me do you use the windows authentication inside the application?

Comment: No, I don't....